# How to embed $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ as a rational normal scroll $S(1,3)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to embed $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ as a rational normal scroll $S(1,3)$?

And another related question: what is a determinantal representation of a singular rational normal scroll, for example, $S(0,1,1)$?